# Identify the Group Name for SharePoint List or document library Item in Site Collection

Tags: powershell, auditing, ssom, spaudit, spauditeventtype

6 months back I had assigned the group name "Designers" to few of the list & 
document library items for a one of the SharePoint site Collection.

Now I would like to find the items holding permission group "Designers"

Can any one help me how can I do this via power-shell or SharePoint Server 
    Object Model